# How to move on from one item at a time through an array? (no setInterval)

Tags: javascript, api

I am making a quiz. How would I be able to make the user, after they answer the question by clicking a button in the multiple choice answer, move onto the next question in the same container div?

```
function runQuizQuestions() {
            // shuffling questions
            let theQuestions = shuffle(myQuestions);
            console.log('shuffled Questions');

            for (let i = 0; i < myQuestions.length; i++) {
                // fill in the questions HTML
                document.querySelector('#quizQ').innerText = myQuestions[i].question;

                document.querySelector('#a1').innerText = myQuestions[i].answer1;
                document.querySelector('#a2').innerText = myQuestions[i].answer2;
                document.querySelector('#a3').innerText = myQuestions[i].answer3;
                document.querySelector('#a4').innerText = myQuestions[i].answer4;
                // store correct answer
                rightAnswer = myQuestions[i].correct;


                // clicking inside the container
                let quizContainer = document.querySelector('#quiz');
                
                quizContainer.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault;
                    let answerClick = event.target;
                    console.log(`you clicked on:`, answerClick);


                    if (answerClick.matches("button")) {
                        // store button's value
                        let answer = answerClick.innerText;
                        // check answer
                        if (answer === rightAnswer) {
                            document.querySelector('#result').innerText = "Correct!";
                            document.querySelector('#result').classList.remove('d-none', 'alert-danger');
                            setTimeout(function () { document.querySelector('#result').classList.add('d-none', 'alert-danger'); }, 2000);
                            console.log('right answer');
                        } else {
                            document.querySelector('#result').innerText = "Wrong!";
                            document.querySelector('#result').classList.remove('d-none', 'alert-success');
                            setTimeout(function () { document.querySelector('#result').classList.add('d-none', 'alert-success'); }, 2000);
                            console.log('wrong answer');
                        }
                    }
                    // move on to next question.
                })
            }
```

Comment: First how is the loop supposed to work if all the questions are put into the same element ( '#quizQ') and overwritten during execution of the loop - leaving only the last question on screen.  Additionally the loopadds as many `click` event listeners as there are questions to the same `#quiz` container. Perhaps updating the post with a small array of questions, the minimal HTML to script depends on to be there, and a description of what is supposed to happen would help us answer your question.

Comment: For more information about posting questions on Stack Overflow you can take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for more specific guidelines.